# How to modify bootstrap menu for mobile to make it similar to facebook mobile menu?

Tags: facebook, mobile, twitter-bootstrap

We are creating a mobile website using twitter bootstrap. We are using the twitter responsive menu.

When we view the menu in mobile it looks like

In the normal mode

[image]

When the menu is expanded.

[image]

can we make it look like facebook mobile style menu i.e. instead of menu being coming from top to bottom, it should come from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

The collapsing of the menu add a css class with transition (on height from 0 to auto). You could overwrite this css class.

Example:

```
.nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse{
    height: 0;
    width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left:100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
     -moz-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
       -o-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
          transition: all 2s ease 0s;
}
.collapse.in {
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This code illustrates only. This code breaks other navbar code. See (open in a small screen): http://bootply.com/74938